# Is there issues on android Webview for SVG? API level16+

Tags: javascript, android, svg, webview

I have  an issue to have SVG(snap.svg) on android Webview:

E/webcoreglue﹕ getAbsoluteBoundingBox failed for node 0xb80d8888, name RenderSVGContainer

E/webcoreglue﹕ getAbsoluteBoundingBox failed for node 0xb80d7d90, name RenderSVGPath

Obviously no error occured in PC webBrowser.

I've googled `E/webcoreglue﹕ getAbsoluteBoundingBox`, but no result.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Anyone know what this is... its killing me!!!

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm currenly looking for solution